# How to send an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header using Django 3?

Tags: django, cors

I'm new to server-side programming and I'm trying to get some information from the backend through the frontend.
The backend, as indicated in the header, is written in Django. The frontend is written in React, if it's important.

There is a view function on the backend, which only returns plain string:

```
 HttpResponse("Some useful information.")
```

This string is available at: "http://localhost:8000/info/". I checked through the browser, it really works.

So, I'm trying to get this string from the frontend, using axios library:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/info/").then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
})
```

An error occurs, when I'm trying to send request. It sounds like this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/info/' from origin 'http://localhost:3006' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

There are no errors on the server side. It returns code 200.

As far as I understand, the data are received on the frontend, but the browser blocks access to it, because the server must additionally attach an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

How can I send this header from the server? Should I configure something in the settings.py or modify the view function? Or maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser's [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is preventing your script from reading the data.

To allow that you need to implement [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

To do that in Django, use the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) package.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, you can set a header by modifying the response before you return it.

```
response = HttpResponse("some useful information")
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:3006"
return response
```

In practice, if you want to send the CORS header for multiple views, then I would suggest using [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/). It has a middleware which sets the header.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser doesn't allow the web application to perform requests to a different origin (scheme, host or port) as a security measure. So if your frontend is served from for instance localhost:5000, you won't be able to access your Django instance on localhost:8000.

If your server specifies `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, your browser will accept a request like this.

Django does not by default add this header, but you can write a middleware for it yourself, or you can use the [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) package to do it for you.

Install this package, then add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

and add its middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

You can then either set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` in your settings to `True` (Not recommended for production environments)

Or set `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to `['http://localhost:8000']`